# ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 pipeline branching and controller namespace constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to use pipeline branching in ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 in such a way that only controllers in namespace xxx.yyy.Pipe1.Controllers are "available" to a branch mapped like this in 'Startup.cs' app.Map("/pipe1", ConfigurePipe1);
What would be the preferred, and/or correct, way to do that?
It is not so much about controller discovery as about restricting the set of controllers that can be resolved during request processing.  My reason for doing this is the need to use different authentication schemes per pipeline, and thereby per set of controllers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to map applications by the corresponding controller's namespace?

I think this is not possible. There is `MapWhen` method. I tried to resolve the controller when it invoked but I had no luck (I knew it was hopeless).

```
app.MapWhen(context => {
    var shouldWeMap = ... // here I tried many things but it was impossible to resolve the controller.
    return shouldWeMap;
}, ConfigurePipe1);
```

If you want to learn which controller will be hit, you have to let asp.net map this request to a mvc configuration. But after doing this, you miss your chance to map that request to an app as already having done it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It uses a custom `IActionFilter` to check which configuration is used in every request.

Just map a new configuration as you suggested before:

```
app.Map("/pipe1", ConfigurePipe1);
```

And then in `ConfigurePipe1` make MVC to MapRoute with a different signature (unique name?). With this way you can implement your own global `IActionFilter` and force it to check which RouteData has been used.

And there you can do whatever you want. Check controller's namespace and so on...

So `ConfigurePipe1` may be like:

```
public void ConfigurePipe1(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomPipeRoute",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    });
}
```

And in custom `IActionFilter` we can check them like:

```
public class GlobalActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controllerNamespace = context.Controller.GetType().Namespace;
        var pipeRoute = context.RouteData.Routers.OfType<TemplateRoute>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "CustomPipeRoute");
        if (pipeRoute != null)
        {
            // We are using /pipe1
        }
        if (.....)
        {
            // You can redirect to somewhere else if you want.
            var controller = (Controller)context.Controller;
            context.Result = controller.RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to register the custom filter as:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(GlobalActionFilter));
});
```